# Why is unicode charactes supported in my programs, without any extra libraries

Tags: c, unix, signals, unicode-string

I have to reproduce a client / server communication with Unix signals, I already done this part however there is a bonus where I have to make my program supports Unicode and it supports it but I don't know why though.

```
void handle_char(int pid, char c)
{
    int i;

    i = 7;
    while (1 << i && i >= 0)
    {
        s_received = 0;
        if ((1 << i) & c)
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        else
            kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
        if (!s_received)
            pause();
        i--;
    }
}
```

As seen in the code above, i take each char of my string and doing binary operation to either send 1 or 0 to my server, I start from 7 to 0 as a byte is 8 bits.

```
void handler(int signal, siginfo_t *client, void *ucontext)
{
    (void)ucontext;
    static int shift = -1;
    static char c;

    is_process_running(client->si_pid);
    /*if (f_msg)
    {
        ft_putstr_fd("\nMessage from process ", 1);
        ft_putnbr_fd((int)client->si_pid, 1);
        ft_putstr_fd(": ", 1);
        f_msg = 0;
    }*/
    if (shift < 0)
        shift = 7;
    if (signal == SIGUSR1)
        c |= (1 << shift);
    shift--;
    if (shift < 0 && c)
    {
        ft_putchar_fd(c, 1);
        c = 0;
    }
    else if (shift < 0 && !c)
        kill(client->si_pid, SIGUSR2);
        //f_msg = 1;
    kill(client->si_pid, SIGUSR1);
}
```

Here is how my server decode it.
This solution was to make me print basic char of utf-8 but as I start from 7 and not 31 why am i able to print utf-32 like emoji or even 'é' ?

Comment: You might want to insert debug-`printf` to watch the bytes transmitted. But without a [mre] we cannot answer, because we don't see how you call `handle_char`.

Comment: If `i` runs down from 7 to 0 then `1 << i` is *always* is != 0 – and with signed int, shifting the 1 into the sign bit (while yet positive) or out of the int entirely would both be undefined behaviour anyway. So the test for is meaningless anyway. You might have your loop as `for(int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) { unsigned char mask = 1u << i; /* ... */ }`; note, too, that `char` might be signed, better change to explicit `unsigned char`.

Comment: Why would you need *signals* for processing utf-8 data??? Im not sure what `ft_putchar_fd` actually does – is it *signal safe*, i.e. would it only use other [signal safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) functions itself? If not or if in doubt of you must not use it within a signal handler anyway!

Comment: UTF-32 is an *encoding*, not a set of characters.  UTF-8 can encode all the same characters that UTF-32 can, and more compactly.  It is unlikely that your program's behavior has anything to do with UTF-32.